# Android: Gallery programatically moving between gallery items

Tags: android, onclick, gallery, android-gallery

I'm trying to move a gallery programatically and its pretty awful out of the box, when using setselection it move instantly to the selection, i want to acheive a nice slide (as if you were using your own finger). The anumate property that comes with gallery appears to do nothing though?

Does anyone know why the Animate doesn't appear to work on Gallery setSelection? I use

```
gallery1.setSelection(currentExercise, true);
gallery1.setAnimationDuration(500);
```

but the gallery continues to change instantly.

I have seen a solution that suggests this use (which is faking a finger slide)

```
gallery1.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
```

which give a better result, but makes an annoying click noise as if I'm pressing a key so its not very appropriate for my purposes?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gallery1.onFling(null, null, 2000,0);`

You will need to experiment with the 2000 value as it depends on the size of the images. It could also depend on the size of the device, if the gallery / iamges get larger on a tablet, than on a phone.

It's not a perfect solution, but it should work.

Comment: I like the idea, but it doesn't do anything when I implement it?